# "Error from server (Timeout): the server was unable to return a response in the time allotted, but may still be processing the request (get nodes)"

Tags: kubernetes

When I use this command: "kubectl get nodes" I get the below errors:

```
Error from server (Timeout): the server was unable to return a response in the time allotted, but may still be processing the request (get nodes)
```

Can anyone help to solve this issue?

Comment: Check this command: `kubectl cluster-info`

Comment: root@k8s-server01:/opt/kubernetes/bin# kubectl cluster-info
Kubernetes master is running at http://localhost:8080

To further debug and diagnose cluster problems, use 'kubectl cluster-info dump'

Comment: It seems like you have problems with iptables on the master. Did you open ports as in the instruction https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/install-kubeadm/#master-node-s ?

Comment: it 's resolved,i used the wrong configuration of KUBE_ETCD_VERSION in apiserver.sh.

Answer (score 1):

As OP @Sam.Yang informed in comment section problem is resolved.

Problem was in the wrong configuration of `KUBE_ETCD_VERSION` in `apiserver.sh`.